# The screensaver will change arbitrarily

Tags: windows

I use windows10. When I start up, my screensaver change to black arbitrarily. If you know the cause, please teach me the reason.I have tried clean installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help. Please visit [Desktop background turned to black automatically. Why?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/desktop-background-keeps-becoming-black/b77ee781-49e1-4014-860b-24d22e66d6e4)